# how can i display image which i am getting from backend in this format �PNG in react

Tags: html, reactjs, image, blob

i want to display image which i am getting in this formate
`
�PNG

....`

how can i do this
[image]

i tryed doing this

```
// 'Screenshot 2023-03-27 173652.png
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: 'image/jpeg',
        });
        const headerLine = response.headers['content-disposition'];
        const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
```

where this imageUrl i am using

`<img src={imageUrl} alt="img" />`

Comment: Can you give a copy of that response.data and the file?

Comment: yes sure i have added a picture of the respone, above